# Unsigned long into char array

Tags: c, linux, pointers, unsigned

Here is an example of my code :

```
/* Standard Linux headers */


/* --------------------------------------------------------------------------
Calculates the CRYPTO 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
unsigned long CalculateCRYPTO(
unsigned long ulCount, /* Number of bytes in the data block */
unsigned char *ucBuffer )  /*Data block*/
{
    unsigned long ulCRYPTO = 0;
    //fonction that i have not coded ...
    return( ulCRYPTO );

}


int main (void)
{

  /*Variables and socket programming*/

   //this is my datablock must be in hexa AA 35 07 (will chnage size and data but for now it's hardcoded)
    unsigned char datablock[3];
    memset(datablock, '\0' ,sizeof(datablock));
    datablock[0]=0xaa;
    datablock[1]=0x35;
    datablock[2]=0x07;

    unsigned long CRYPTO;
    CRYPTO=CalculateCRYPTO(sizeof(datablock),datablock); //calculate crypto depending of datablocks
    printf("CRYPTO = 0x%08x \n", CRYPTO); //prints me 0xe8ba8fa3 that is what i want 

    /*Creating the final command*/
    //(will chnage size and data but for now it's fixed)
    unsigned char cmd_final_hex[7]; //this needs to be DATABLOCKS+CRYPTO
                                    //in hexa AA 35 07 concatenated to inverted CRYPTO so ... A3 8F BA E8 => must be AA 35 07 A3 8F BA E8
    memset(cmd_final_hex, '\0' ,sizeof(cmd_final_hex));     //Make sure cmd final is at 0
    memcpy(cmd_final_hex, datablock, sizeof(datablock));    //cmd at datablock + 000
    // while loop prints me what i want so cmd_final_hex[]=AA 35 07 00 00 ...

    //Now i want to concatenate so my idea is to use memcpy and not strcat :
    memcpy(&cmd_final_hex[sizeof(datablock)], &CRYPTO, 4);

   //and a print gives me AA 35 07 A3 8F BA E8 which is exactly what i want but why do i have to use "&CRYPTO" and not "CRYPTO" in my memcpy. !!!

  return 0;


}
```

My question is, why does this last memcpy works ? i would expect to put CRYPTO and not &CRYPTO in arguments... For me, CRYPTO is the value i want so 0xe8ba8fa3 and &CRYPTO the address. And for me, CRYPTO is not a pointer, so why i need to use memcpy with &CRYPTO to make it works ?

By the way, my code may be pure disaster, i'm a beginner. Do not hesitate to correct me !

Thank you !

Comment: great job on creating a [MCVE]! I feel however that it can be improved. There are still parts of it that are irrelevant to your issue. Here's how I think a better MCVE could look: https://pastebin.com/3QcR7bLi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My question is, why does this last memcpy works ? i would expect to
>   put CRYPTO and not &CRYPTO in arguments... For me, CRYPTO is the value
>   i want so 0xe8ba8fa3 and &CRYPTO the address.

You're right. `CRYPTO` is not a pointer. However, [memcpy](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_memcpy.htm) expects a pointer, so we have to give it one. We do this by taking `CRYPTO` 's address, and this is done by adding `&` to it, hence `&CRYPTO`.

What `memcpy` does is copying the memory from one address to the other address (that's why it takes two pointers), regardless of the actual content at those addresses. If you gave it `CRYPTO` instead of a pointer to it, it would likely interpret the value of `CRYPTO` as an address (the behavior is undefined, there's no guarantee for what will happen unless the compiler gives one).

Comment: Okay ! Thanks ! So if i understand well, &CRYPTO can be used as the pointer of CRYPTO since it contains the address of CRYPTO ?

Comment: No problem, glad it helped.

Comment: "If you gave it `CRYPTO` instead of a pointer to it, it would interpret the value of `CRYPTO` as an address" -- that is one thing that might happen, but the behavior is undefined when incorrect types are passed in function calls.

Answer (score 1):

For [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/?kw=memcpy)

***memcpy*** `void * memcpy ( void * destination, const void * source, size_t num );`

**Parameters**

- ***destination*** : Pointer to the destination array where the content is to be copied, type-casted to a pointer of type void*.
- ***source*** : Pointer to the source of data to be copied, type-casted to a pointer of type const void*.
- ***num*** : Number of bytes to copy. size_t is an unsigned integral type.